# Getting data from external json file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I am currently using JQuery to read an external .json file containing data for a photo slideshow

photo-slideshow.json

```
 [ 
        {
            "title" : "my tile", 
            "image" : "xx.jpg", 
            "url" : "www.example.com",
            "firstline" : "woow", 
            "secondline" : "the weather is fine"
        },

       .....
       ..... 
    ]

    <script type="text/javascript" >
    var photos; 
    $.getJSON(
           "lang/en/photo-slideshow.json", 
            function(result) {
                    photos = result;
            }
       );
    <script>
```

The script works fine on pages that take longer to load! On pages loading very quickly (e.g. 1 sec)
the json file doesn`t seem to be read completely and the slideshow doesn`t start.

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing the slideshow after the json callback is fired?

As you are performing an async call for a json object, your slideshow initialization should be in a callback function fired by the getJson to ensure you really has the data at hand when needed.

You should do something like this:

```
$.getJSON('path/to/my.json',function(result){
    mySlideShowComponent.init(result);
})
```

Comment: async call didn`t solve the problem. The Slideshow is being initialized after but sometimes starting before before i get the data from the json file.

Comment: Then you need to make it async as the data shouldn't be fetchd synchronously.
Otherwise it may probably never work as expected.

Comment: .getJSON is async, and you code expects something to be sync.
Would you mind sharing the whole code? So i could analyze it better.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it! i put this line to my code: $.ajaxSetup({async:false}); Thanks